# How do you identify if Network Preferences are set to Manual IP address or DHCP in terminal

Tags: networking, terminal, dhcp

I'm managing about 20 Macs and I'd like to quickly determine if the network preferences are correctly set to have a static IP address or (incorrectly) using DHCP. Is there a way to run a query through Apple Remote Desktop or simple terminal command to find that out?